# Scale Vagrant VM disk usage automatically

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrant

I have a vagrant box that has about 6gb of disk space. How do I change this so that the vm takes up as much space as needed? I see plenty of space on my laptop:

Vagrant:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                       6744840   6401512       700 100% /
tmpfs                   749960         0    749960   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1               495844     40707    429537   9% /boot
v-root               487385240 332649828 154735412  69% /vagrant
```

Laptop:

```
~ $ df
Filesystem    512-blocks      Used Available Capacity  iused    ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1     974770480 662925656 311332824    69% 82929705 38916603   68%   /
devfs                390       390         0   100%      675        0  100%   /dev
map -hosts             0         0         0   100%        0        0  100%   /net
map auto_home          0         0         0   100%        0        0  100%   /home
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to make dynamically sized disks with virtual box as far as I am aware... They always need to have a max size even though they can be dynamically allocated.

Resizing them is also quite complicated but there are several tutorials around on the net, for example something like this should get you on the right track: http://tanmayk.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/resizing-a-virtualbox-partition/

I usually make sure that the vagrant box I choose to use or create has about 40 gigs as the size for the dynamically allocated disk.